# Perform javascript based search on reaching 3 characters on input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have html table with more than 2000 data also have code for live javascript search for this html search.when i am entering first character in text box javascript start searching ,what i want if the characters reach more than three i want to perform search function,if the character is below three no search function.below is my javascript code,can anyone guide me how to do it .thanks

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function searchRows(CPH_GridView1) {
var tbl = document.getElementById(CPH_GridView1);
var headRow = tbl.rows[0];
var arrayOfHTxt = new Array();
var arrayOfHtxtCellIndex = new Array();

for (var v = 0; v < headRow.cells.length; v++) {
 if (headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]) {
 var Htxtbox = headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  if (Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') != '') {
    arrayOfHTxt.push(Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
    arrayOfHtxtCellIndex.push(v);
  }
 }
}

for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

    tbl.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';

    for (var v = 0; v < arrayOfHTxt.length; v++) {

        var CurCell = tbl.rows[i].cells[arrayOfHtxtCellIndex[v]];

        var CurCont = CurCell.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");

        var reg = new RegExp(arrayOfHTxt[v] + ".*", "i");

        if (CurCont.match(reg) == null) {

            tbl.rows[i].style.display = 'none';

       }

    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meet your requirement i have made some changes.Please replace your code with mine.

your code:

```
if (Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') != '') {
 arrayOfHTxt.push(Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
 arrayOfHtxtCellIndex.push(v);
}
```

My code:

```
var content = Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
if (content != '' && content.length >= 3) {
 arrayOfHTxt.push(Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
 arrayOfHtxtCellIndex.push(v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it working.may i asking you question i have more the 2000 data showing in table when i search it showing data very fast,if i delete the search data it showing all the data but its very slow to show all the data,do you have any idea about it ,thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

In the begining of your `for` cycle validate your input:

```
var keyword = headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
if(keyword===undefined || keyword.length < 3) {
    return false;
}
```

Also, you can use the defined `keyword` variable later in your code, just to increase readability.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L99wM/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried like this  for (var v = 0; v < headRow.cells.length; v++) {
var keyword = headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
if(keyword.length < 3) {
    return false;
}
 if (headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]) {
 var Htxtbox = headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  if (Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') != '') {
    arrayOfHTxt.push(Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
    arrayOfHtxtCellIndex.push(v);
  }
 }
}
its showing  TypeError: keyword is undefined(13 out of range 2)

Comment: Modified it. Its now uses onkeyup event not onchange.

Comment: thank you,may i asking you question i have more the 2000 data showing in table when i search it showing data very fast,if i delete the search data it showing all the data but its very slow to show all the data,do you have any idea about it .

Comment: Have you heard about this? http://datatables.net Maybe it is good for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the keyup function in jquery

```
jQuery (element).keyup (function () {
if (jQuery (this).length > 3) {
//call search method here.
}
});
```

Comment: There is no single line of jQuery code in the question, do you suggest to implement the complete library just to capture one event?

Comment: Oh yes Sorry I did n't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

concisely :

```
<input name="Field1" value="" type="text" onkeyup="if(this.value.length>2) {searchFor(this.value)}">
```

then have a function :

```
searchFor(val) {
 // code to search for something here
}
```

Or more elegantly (so  you define the checking function in one place):

```
<input name="Field1" value="" type="text"  onkeyup="checkFld(this)">
```

then have script function ..
    function checkFld(fld) {
      var val = fld.value;
      if (val.length<3)  {return}
      alert("Search for " + val)
    // search code goes here
    }